# Is there any problem due to dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c, loops, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char* name;
}Student;

int main()  {

    int n,i;

    printf("Enter the number of student: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    Student *ptr = (Student*) malloc(n * sizeof(Student));

    for( i = 0; i < n ;i++)  {

        printf("Enter the name of student: ");
        scanf("%s", (ptr + i)->name);


    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I couldn't understand why this code is not working can anyone help me ? I thought the problem is dynamic memory allocation but i couldn't solve.

Comment: HI, perhaps initialize the `name` pointer?

Comment: Note that the `(Student *)` cast is only required if you need C++ compatibility.

Comment: @IronMan but if the code is " char * name; scanf("%s", name);" the exit code is 0. so there is no problem(in my opinion) with initialization of name.

Comment: `char *name` creates a pointer to `char` named `name`, and a pointer can only store memory address, it is not possible to store a string in it. To store a string you need an array of `char` (of sufficient length).

Comment: The type of the expression `(ptr + i)->name` is a `pointer to char`, right? What do you think where the `(ptr + i)->name` *points to*?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. The name is not allocated memory. This is what you made for mistakes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char* name;
}Student;

int main()  {

    int n,i;

    printf("Enter the number of student: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    Student *ptr = (Student*) malloc(n * sizeof(Student));

    for( i = 0; i < n ;i++)  {

        printf("Enter the name of student: ");
        char str[1024];
        scanf("%s", str);
        (ptr + i)->name = (char*)malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
        strcpy((ptr + i)->name, str);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Note that the `(char *)` and `(Student *)` casts are only required if you need C++ compatibility.

Comment: Try and use something more generous, like `1024` as a buffer size. 100 bytes is nothing.

Comment: I'm just saying your buffer is super tiny and 1024 is a safer default than 100.

Comment: but if the code is " char * name; scanf("%s", name);" the exit code is 0. so there is no problem(in my opinion) with initialization of name.